# Как будет hash (хеш) по-русски?

Tags: хеширование, hashcode

Для написания дипломных работ требуют использования только русских слов, а не заимствованных из английского языка. Например нельзя использовать: брандмауэр, логин, браузер.  На английском можно только название программ, ОС и т.д. Друзья, есть ли у Вас идеи, как называют хеш (в моем случае хеш пароля) в научной литературе на русском?

Я встречал - "дайджест сообщения", но "дайджест" тоже английское слово "digest". Видел перевод "сводка сообщения" в википедии, но никаких материалов, где такое словосочетание используется нет.

Comment: а это возможно?

Comment: с тем же успехом можно запретить использовать слова "компьютер" или "интернет"

Comment: у меня просили заменить слово "пакет" потому что "не понятно"

Comment: Spectre, здесь как раз тонкая грань между словами устоявшимися и описанными в нормативных документах и словами, для которых есть логичный русский аналог.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В ГОСТ Р 34.11-94, начиная прямо с названия, используется слово «хэш» и его производные («хэширование»).

Так что с этим словом все в порядке.

За исключением вопроса правописания («хэш» или «хеш»). В ГОСТах тут слегка разброд и шатания, два ГОСТа одного года (34.10-94 и 34.11-94; да, первый неактуален, см. далее) использовали разные варианты («хеш» и «хэш» соотв.), в ГОСТ 34.10-2001 уже «хэш.» Так что, скорее всего, через «э», но тут я не уверен. Это, лучше, спросите на gramota.ru :)

Comment: Ну раз ГОСТ так говорит, значит и мы так будем говорить) Спасибо, не пришло мне в голову в ГОСТ заглянуть.

Answer (score 7):

Формально может быть подходит [контрольная сумма](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0), но лично у меня возникают  не те ассоциации.

В советской научной литературе (насколько помню) для организации поиска в  хэш-таблицах  когда-то применяли термин **перемешивание** (и производные от него), но он был успешно вытеснен хэшированием.

Вместо "дайджест" можно было бы использовать *подпись*, но это несколько конфликтует с смыслом, вкладываемом ныне в термин ЭЦП (электронная цифровая подпись).

А по делу, могу только выразить Вам свои самые искренние соболезнования.

Comment: Дайджест = хэш-сумма.

Comment: Ершов использовал слово «расстановка», см. [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D1%8D%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Переводчик "Искусства программирования. Том 3" в разделе 6.4 "Хэширование" упоминает в примечании о гипотетическом варианте перевода этого слова как «окрошка»

Answer (score 3):

И хеш, и дайджест [есть в википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0), как и само понятия ["хеширование"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), которое я многократно встречал в русскоязычной технической литературе. Так что, я думаю, можете смело использовать!

Другое дело с логином, браузером и брендмауэром - для них википедия предлагает "идентификатор учетной записи", "веб-обозреватель" и "межсетевой экран". А слово "хеш" - официально используется в русском языке, и при этом, конечно, является заимствованным. Я думаю вы немного ошибаетесь, когда пишете, что нельзя использовать именно **заимствованные** слова, ведь заимствованными [по факту](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5) являются почти все названия наук и большая часть терминов. Я уверен, что вам запретили использовать именно слова взятые из английского языка и записанные русскими буквами с максимально похожим произношением, при этом не входящие официально в состав русского языка.

Comment: Согласен, правильно поправили. Заимствованные слова - немного не то.